# How to groom a double coated dog?

Tags: dogs, grooming

Our rough-coated collie pup should be arriving within mere weeks now! We just visited/played with the five week old pups, right as the breeders were actively determining the "frontrunners" for show and agility.

I've searched the internet and found some pretty specific information (use a combination of a "rake" and a "pin brush"), but wanted to cross reference that with the wealth of knowledge here.

My plan is to do 10-15 minute touch up brushings during the week (ah, quiet time for Mom), with a much longer and serious brushing over the weekend.

My breeder says they only do the weekend heavy grooming on even their best show/agility dog, and that the proper collie coat is actually easy to take care of. That dog not only looks (and is) AWESOME but is the grandsire of our pup!

However, I did read the suggestion online that ours might be less easy to care for because we are going to spay/neuter as we are a "companion pet" home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rake is likely all you will need. Using a rake with tines that spin is even better. You should get the puppy used to being bushed a little at a time, don't over do it at first or you might teach it to hate being brushed. You won't really need the brushing for a little while anyway as he won't shed much when he is young.

You can also use a mat cutter easily get through his "feathering" and collar. I usually start with that around any area that seems a little tangled then use a rake over the full coat. If you are grooming for show this would likely be "not advised" as you would be thinning/cutting the area you use the mat cutter on. So read this as "companion pet" advice not a show groom advice.

Start brushing towards his rear and move up towards his head as you go. You won't have as hard of a time getting through his undercover that way. But if he has a nice coat and you keep up on it then it shouldn't be hard anyway.

The only real difference in coat between an altered and and intact dog is that the altered dogs tend to shed less but more often and the intact tend to shed a ton but all at once. Intact males can develop more of a collar too.

Comment: I hadn't seen or heard of a rake with spinning tines--what a great idea! I already have a rake and don't know if the tines spin or not (hadn't thought to look), but will upgrade if I need to.